# How to get userID when writing Linux kernel module

Tags: kernel

Here is my function in my kernel module which I insert using `insmod` command after `make` at later stages. I am working on  `goldfish (2.6.29)`

```
asmlinkage long our_sys_read(unsigned int fd, char  *buf, size_t count)
{
      printk("------->> our_sys_read getuid() ---------- %d\n", getuid());

      return original_call_read(fd,buf,count);
}
```

I want to trap system calls and find out which user made these system calls. But when I run 'make', it throws me following error.

```
/home/mohsin/LKM/trapcall.c:245: error: implicit declaration of function 'getuid'
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I wont go as far as marking this offtopic but it does feel like it is not about Ubuntu ;) I would suggest asking this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ since I see lots more kernel questions there than on AU.

Answer (score -1):

Use `get_current_user()->uid;` instead of `get`.